# Programatically add and bind DataGrid column

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, data-binding, datagrid

I want to add a column programatically to my datagrid and bind it.

I have tried following examples on the web but cant get the data do be displayed.

I did have it working with columns declared in the xaml.

Here is the datagrid Xaml declaration:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="0" x:Name="dtgMain" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}" RowHeight="25" SizeChanged="dtgMain_SizeChanged"></DataGrid>
```

Here is where I set the datacontext for the datagrid:

```
System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
                doc.LoadXml(response);
                provider.Document = doc;
                provider.XPath = "/moo/response/data/load/panel";
                dtgMain.DataContext = provider;
```

Here is where I add the column:

```
DataGridTextColumn dc = new DataGridTextColumn();
            dc.Binding = new Binding("panelCode");
            dc.Header = "Job Number";
            dtgMain.Columns.Add(dc);
```

And here is an example of the xml:

```
<moo>
  <response>
    <data>
      <load count="2">true
        <panel index="10">
          <panelCode>100072
          </panelCode>
        </panel>
      </load>
    </data>
  </response>
</moo>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your column binding is not using `XPath` when it should it seems to me.

```
dc.Binding = new Binding() { XPath = "panelCode" };
```

Comment: like I said this code was working fine when the columns were declared in the xaml. So im guessing the issue Is something to do witht eh way im declaring the binding on the datacolumn. I just tried this and it still does not work.

Comment: I assumed that since I use Xpath to set my datacontext that the binding of the datacolumn would start in the xml from that point? So would it be something like dc.Binding = new Binding("/moo/response/data/load/panel/panelCode");

Comment: @user589195: Check out [debugging data bindngs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx) by the way.

Comment: @user589195: See my edit. Your source object in every row is an XmlElement, if you want to bind xml you need XPath.